# pdfmake - cant find the font files on vfs

Tags: javascript, fonts, pdfmake

I have the following code I am using to test drive `PDFmake`.
I am having an issue with the location of the font files. I see documentation that seem to indicate that after pulling in the **vfs_fonts** file that I should be able to see them. However this is not the case for me.

```
function createPdf(assessmentId: string): string {
  const pdfMake = require('pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js');
  const pdfFonts = require('pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js');
  pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;

  //required font setup, requires that you link to the fonts shipped with npm

  const fontDescriptors = {
    Roboto: {
      normal: 'Roboto-Regular.ttf',
      bold: 'Roboto-Medium.ttf',
      italics: 'Roboto-Italic.ttf',
      bolditalics: 'Roboto-Italic.ttf',
    }
  };
  const termpaper = new PdfLayout();
  const docDefinition = termpaper.layout
  const printer = new Printer(fontDescriptors);

  //get a reference to the PdfKit instance, which is a streaming interface

  const pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);

  return "pdflocation";
}
```

When this code executes I get this error.

> Error:
>
> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Roboto-Medium.ttf'
>       at Error (native)
>       at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:642:18)
>       at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:510:33)
>       at Object.fontkit.openSync (/user_code/node_modules/pdfmake/node_modules/fontkit/index.js:43:19)
>       at Function.PDFFont.open (/user_code/node_modules/pdfmake/node_modules/pdfkit/js/font.js:14:24)
>       at PDFDocument.font (/user_code/node_modules/pdfmake/node_modules/pdfkit/js/mixins/fonts.js:39:28)
>       at FontProvider.provideFont (/user_code/node_modules/pdfmake/src/fontProvider.js:49:58)
>       at /user_code/node_modules/pdfmake/src/textTools.js:258:27
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at measure (/user_code/node_modules/pdfmake/src/textTools.js:240:13)

What do I need to do to properly find these font files?

Answer (score 9):

I struggled with this too. The solution I found was to actually include the font files in my project. The files listed are in the 'fonts' folder at the root of my project, and my code references them by uri:

```
const fonts = {
    Roboto: {
        normal: 'fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
        bold: 'fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf',
        italics: 'fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
        bolditalics: 'fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf'
    }
};
```

I downloaded the font files from [here](http://www.1001fonts.com/roboto-font.html).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use like this, In my case my fonts, controllers, helper directory inside workspace directory.

```
const path = require('path'); // path is give you a working directory path.resolve() and you can give your font file path.

const fontDescriptors = {
  Roboto: {
    normal: path.resolve('./fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf'),
    bold: path.resolve('./fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf'),
    italics: path.resolve('./fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf'),
    bolditalics: path.resolve('./fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Had similar problem once, you needed to give exact location of the fonts.

It also has marked notification before fonts.

> //required font setup, **requires that you link to the fonts shipped with npm**

Try full directory paths on these:

```
    normal: '/Exampledir/pdfmake/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
    bold: 'Roboto-Medium.ttf',
    italics: 'Roboto-Italic.ttf',
    bolditalics: 'Roboto-Italic.ttf',
```

Or there is / missing from

const pdfFonts = require("pdfmake/

Eg.

const pdfFonts = require("/pdfmake/

It was that simple as error indicates it can't find fonts from that location, overcheck the location with simple cd ./ then cd /pdfmake/ etc and ls. Compare config file and should get it working.

Answer (score 2):

You can very well use custom fonts by simple 3 steps :

To **use custom fonts**, 3 steps are required:

- create vfs_fonts.js containing your fonts
- define font family
- change font family in doc-definition-object

**1. Create vfs_fonts.js containing your fonts**

> Copy your fonts to myProject/fonts/ directory
>
> Run grunt dump_dir (you can update Gruntfile.js if you'd like to change base directory or add an alternative config for dump_dir task)
>
> Use your new **build/vfs_fonts.js** on your web page
>
> BTW - the above action dumps all files from myProject/fonts/ (not only fonts), which means you could put images there, run grunt dump_dir and reference them by name in doc-definition-object

**2. Define font family**

> Before calling `pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition)` set **pdfMake.fonts** to the following object:

```
{
   yourFontName: {
     normal: 'fontFile.ttf',
     bold: 'fontFile2.ttf',
     italics: 'fontFile3.ttf',
     bolditalics: 'fontFile4.ttf'
   },
   anotherFontName: {
     (...)
   }
}
```

> > Keys are font-family names you can later use in doc-definition
> >
> > > Each font-family defines 4 properties: normal, bold, italics and bold-italics referring to appropriate files (by default these are file paths relative to **myProject/fonts/**)
>
> By default pdfMake uses the following structure:

```
{
        Roboto: {
                normal: 'Roboto-Regular.ttf',
                bold: 'Roboto-Medium.ttf',
                italics: 'Roboto-Italic.ttf',
                bolditalics: 'Roboto-Italic.ttf'
        }
};
```

**3. Change font family in doc-definition-object**

> Currently pdfmake uses 'Roboto' as default family name, so in order to use your font, you should change it. The easiest way is to do it globally in defaultStyle

```
var docDefinition = {
  content: (...),
  defaultStyle: {
    font: 'yourFontName'
  }
}
```

So, ideally, I would suggest you to download and put all the **font files** you want in a folder, say **myProject/fonts/** and then try referencing the same in your code. The correct snippet of your code would look similar to this :

```
const fontDescriptors = {
    Roboto: {
      normal: 'myProject/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
      bold: 'myProject/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf',
      italics: 'myProject/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
      bolditalics: 'myProject/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
    }
};
```

Hope this would solve your issue. Feel free to ask doubts, if any.

Answer (score 1):

This error mostly comes when you work with webpack. We are using webpack and managed to fix this by shimming this to window with the webpack imports-loader like this:

*`var fonts = require('imports?this=>window!pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js');`*

**Fix:**

```
function createPdf(assessmentId: string): string {

  const pdfMake = require('pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js');

  const pdfFonts = require('pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js');// this line will give an error if you are working with webpack .
```

> var fonts =
>   require('imports?this=>window!pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js'); //use this line to fix it

```
  pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;

  //required font setup, requires that you link to the fonts shipped with npm

  const fontDescriptors = {
    Roboto: {
      normal: 'Roboto-Regular.ttf',
      bold: 'Roboto-Medium.ttf',
      italics: 'Roboto-Italic.ttf',
      bolditalics: 'Roboto-Italic.ttf',
    }
  };
  const termpaper = new PdfLayout();
  const docDefinition = termpaper.layout
  const printer = new Printer(fontDescriptors);

  //get a reference to the PdfKit instance, which is a streaming interface

  const pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);

  return "pdflocation";
}
```

Hope this can be helpful for others!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using React and datatables.net. This is what worked for me:

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

import 'datatables.net-bs';
import 'datatables.net-buttons-bs';
import 'datatables.net-responsive-bs';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.js';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.js';
import 'jszip';
import pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css';

$.DataTable = require('datatables.net');
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs; // This line solved the Roboto errors

require("datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.js"); // Column visibility
require("datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js"); // HTML 5 file export
require("datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.js"); // Flash file export
require("datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js"); // Print view button
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue. I have tried to follow the steps on [their docs](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/fonts/custom-fonts-client-side/vfs/) but I found the same error as you did. My fonts were successfully added to a subdirectory in my node_modules. My mistake was when I ran the command `gulp buildFonts`, it didn't add the prepared fonts in the vfs_fonts.js file.

It turns out that we have to put the fonts exactly in `examples/fonts` subdirectory. Or alternatively you can reconfigure the gulpfile.js so the default subdirectory is changed to the one you wanted to put the fonts to.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For those who use React (TypeScript) with Vite and end up here, I managed to find a very easy solution for this.

PDFMake Docs says you should import the library as follows:

```js
import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';

(pdfMake as any).vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
```

This works fine in development but when build the app, "pdfFonts.pdfMake" becomes **undefined**. So it doesn't work.

So I analyzed the production build and saw that the build contains a part like this which inludes the fonts object

```js
globalThis.pdfMake = globalThis.pdfMake || {};
globalThis.pdfMake.vfs = {
    "Roboto-Italic.ttf": "AAEAAAARAQAABAAQR0RFRqWLoiAAAdT4AA=...",
    "Roboto-Medium.ttf": "AAEAAAARAQAABAAQR0RFRqWLoiAAAb9IAA...",
    "Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf": "AAEAAAARAQAABAAQR0RFRqWLoiAAAd==....",
    "Roboto-Regular.ttf": "AAEAAAARAQAABAAQR0RFRqWLoiAAAb8IAAACWA=....",
};
```

Since the fonts are already there, we can use them to resolve the issue:

```js
import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';

(pdfMake as any).vfs =
  pdfFonts && pdfFonts.pdfMake ? pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs : globalThis.pdfMake.vfs;
```

Now this will work on both development phase and production build without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I proceeded differently because Vite was highlighting an error (even if the software was built).

I'm using Typescript.

```
const newPdfMake = {
    ...pdfMake,
    vfs: pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs,
}
newPdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition as TDocumentDefinitions).open()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
function createPdf(assessmentId: string): string {
  const pdfMake = require("pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js");
  const pdfFonts = require("pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js");
  pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
  const projectId = "crds-wayfinder-int";
  const philstorage = new gcs({
    projectId: projectId
  });

  // required font setup, requires that you link to the fonts shipped with npm

  const termpaper = new PdfLayout();
  const docDefinition = termpaper.layout;

  // get a reference to the PdfKit instance, which is a streaming interface
  const pdfDoc = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
  pdfDoc.getBuffer((buffer: any) => {
    console.log('buffer: ', buffer);
  });

  console.log('pdfDoc: ', pdfDoc);

  return "pdflocation";
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the issue here? your answer mentions **fonts nowhere**.

Answer (score -1):

for electron (@vue-cli with electron-builder) this finally worked for me:

```
yarn add pdfmake
```

then in js/coffeescript code:

```
import pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js'
import pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js'

# this did the trick:
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs
```

hope that helps!